# cron script can't see files in Desktop

Tags: files, cron, macos

It appears that my script, when run via `cron`, does not see the contents of my Desktop:

~/Code/scripts/problem.sh:

```
echo hello
cd ~/Desktop
echo $(pwd)
ls
echo hello2
```

Output when I run `bash problem.sh` from inside ~/Code/scripts:

```
hello
/Users/alfordsimon/Desktop
calendar.png
*more desktop files
hello2
```

crontab file:

```
* * * * * bash ~/Code/scripts/problem.sh >> ~/Code/scripts/problem.out
```

problem.out contents confirms that the script is running, but for some reason the Desktop files aren't showing:

```
hello
/Users/alfordsimon/Desktop
hello2
```

I haven't bothered trying to see if this issue is present for other directories. I'm trying to have a script automatically move my Screenshot files from Desktop to ~/Documents/screenshots every day (for testing purposes, the script currently runs every minute). What's going on? This is on my macbook—do I have to give my script permission to view Desktop files or something?

Comment: Change the `~` to `$HOME`.

Comment: See https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Comment: Thanks so much. The osxdaily article's process fixed it.